# How to turn on Development bundling in react native for android?

Tags: react-native

I developed an app and then a created the debug version which will run without server for the app by creating the bundle manually.

How can I get back to dev mode, where I can see live Reload options?

When I am running react-native run-android it do start metro bundler but it does not bundles the changes made.

And also, dev setting does not come in phone by shaking.

Tried suggested changes from other SO threads but it didn't work.

```
project.ext.react = [
entryFile: "index.js",
enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
bundleInDebug: true,
devDisabledInDebug: false,
bundleInRelease: false
```

]

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Application class, I have changed the below piece of code. This solved my issue.

```
 public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return true; // earlier it was BuildConfig.DEBUG
    }
```